# check if WCHAR contains string

Tags: c++, wchar

I have variable `WCHAR sDisplayName[1024];`

How can I check if `sDisplayName` contains the string "example"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if(wcscmp(sDisplayName, L"example") == 0)
    ; //then it contains "example"
else
    ; //it does not
```

This does not cover the case where the string in `sDisplayName` starts with "example" or has "example" in the middle. For those cases, you can use `wcsncmp` and `wcsstr`.

Also this check is case sensitive.

Also this will break if `sDisplayName` contains garbage - i. e. is not null terminated.

Consider using std::wstring instead. That's the C++ way.

EDIT: if you want to match the beginning of the string:

```
if(wcsncmp(sDisplayName, L"Adobe", 5) == 0)
    //Starts with "Adobe"
```

If you want to find the string in the middle

```
if(wcsstr(sDisplayName, L"Adobe") != 0)
    //Contains "Adobe"
```

Note that wcsstr returns *nonzero* if the string is found, unlike the rest.

Comment: this does not works if (wcscmp(sDisplayName, L"Adobe") == 0) when sDisplayName = 0x0045e084 L"Adobe AIR"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wchar_t` [variants of standard C functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (i.e., `wcsstr`).

Answer (score 0):

wscstr will find your string anywhere in sDisplayName, wsccmp will see if sDisplayName is exactly your string.